# implement ASP MVP return json as Sails Js MVP return json

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I Want to implement this code in sails js Controller

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
    //Here MyDatabaseEntities is our entity datacontext (see Step 4)
      using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
      {
         var v = dc.Events.OrderBy(a => a.StartAt).ToList();
         return new JsonResult { Data = v, JsonRequestBehavior = 
         JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent promise based sailsjs controller would look like this;

```
getEvents: function(req, res) {
    Events.find().sort('StartAt DESC').then(function(events){
        return res.ok(events);
    }).catch(function(err){
        return res.serverError({"message" : "An error occurred while trying to process your request"});
    });
},
```

Also, the route(which is located in the config/routes.js file) would look like;

```
'GET /': {
    controller: 'EventController',
    action: 'getEvents'
},
```

But most importantly, you need to look at the official sails documentation. For your question, the documentation on models, controllers and routing would give you enough information to understand better. 
- https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models
- https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers
- https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes